# No "Privileges" in PHPMyAdmin, already tried deleting cookies/using FF/loggin in as 'root'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm well aware this has been asked lots of times before but none of the answers so far has been applicable for me or solved the problem.

- I want to run SQL Queries from Python using MySQLdb
- I get
  `OperationalError: (1130, "Host '77-172-143-12.ip.telfort.nl' is not
  allowed to connect to this MySQL server")`
- This IP (77-172-143-12) is
  for configuring my own router (at home)
- I should create a new `USER` for this
  but I don't have the privileges to `CREATE USER...`s
- The `Privileges` tab is missing from PHPMyAdmin, also when I use Firefox and delete all cookies.
- I can't log in
  with `root` and a blank password: I got only one username/login from
  my web hosting company when I registered my domain with them.
- The
  database is on a remote server which I don't manage myself and I seem
  not to have any access to any MySQL config files.

How could this possibly be solved?

**UPDATE**

I understood from the answers that I can't solve this myself since my **hosting provider doesn't allow it** (by default anyway). I'll contact them to see whether they're willing and able to do something about it.

If somebody else has the same problem: as a **workaround** I'll keep using my Python routines on my local `MySQL` database. I'll then use the Wordpress export and import tools to transfer my (updated) local database to the remote server where my website is located. That's not too bad since it will also result in frequent backups of my articles.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal that phpMyAdmin does not show you the Privileges (or Users in recent versions) tab, since you're not privileged.

Usually, on shared servers, hosting providers also use a shared MySQL server, thus they won't allow you root access.

They usually also allow MySQL access only from their web server and not from your home machine, as an additional security measure.

Comment: thanks for the answer! So it means I can only interact with my database from the Wordpress interface or PHPMyAdmin interface? That's good to know but it's pretty bad news too!

Comment: Some host providers also offer shell access, ask the provider.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your hostname (see [myip.nl](http://myip.nl)) as a new host in DirectAdmin and then you can connect to the database on a remote server from a local application (Python in this case). See the screenshot below (sorry it's in Dutch!)

[image]